# How to generate a full server stack in Java with API for CRUD operations from a data model?

Tags: java, rest, api, server, datamodel

**Motivation**: All the servers I've developed have many of the same characteristics, though all differ in implementation.

The question is

> How to engineer a full server stack in Java with the following requirements?
>   And if it can be engineered, can it be generated?

Requirements:

1. Data driven resource oriented CRUD - The data model could be a DB table/s, a class with hibernate annotation or some other industry standard. The stack should support CRUD operations.
2. Industry standard end points - example: REST (Jersey 2).
3. Pluggable - Enable adding additional business logic, from simply adding some info or disabling some of the CRUD operations - to cross cutting concerns, like audit, analytics, etc.
4. Extensible and reusable - Enable adding new endpoints that can use generated code.
5. Authorization/Authentication - Provide access control. Probably should not do full user management, but rather have some plug to connect to some auth vendor (oauth2?).

The requirements should be the basics. Anything I missed?

Comment: IMO this is a sophisticated version of "give me the codez". It's extremely broad and opinion based as well. I don't really see how you can turn this into a question suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Do you recommend another StackExchange site to post this question on? I would think that for every question there is/willbe a suitable SE site :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into [Jhipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/) generator. It covers most (if not all) of your requirements.